# C# Divide points based on players damage

Tags: unity, c#

How can i divide points based on highest damage? For e.g i have monster which drop 50 experience points and 4 different players has dealt damage to this monster. But i will like to split the experience points based on the players damage.

So far i got this:

```
private Dictionary<Player, int> damageMap = new Dictionary<Player, int>();

public void TakeDamage(Player attacker, int damage)
{
    damageMap.Add(attacker, damage);
}

private void OnDeath()
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Player, int> entry in damageMap)
    {
        Player player = entry.Key;
        int damage = entry.Value;

        player.addExperience(50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have experience as a float

```
float totalExperience = 50.0f;
foreach (KeyValuePair<Player, int> entry in damageMap)
{
    Player player = entry.Key;
    int damage = entry.Value;

    float playerDamageFraction = (float)damage/(float)totalMonsterHealth;

    player.addExperience(totalExperience * playerDamageFraction);
}
```

Should work

If your experience is an int then do the same thing but round to an int at the last step

```
player.addExperience(Mathf.RoundToInt(totalExperience * playerDamageFraction));
```

---

This is beyond the scope of your question but I noticed that you may find you have a problem with your `TakeDamage()` function

```
public void TakeDamage(Player attacker, int damage)
{
    damageMap.Add(attacker, damage);
}
```

Probably needs to be

```
public void TakeDamage(Player attacker, int damage)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(player)){ 
        damageMap[player] += damage;
    } else{
        damageMap.Add(attacker, damage);
    }
}
```

To get the behavior you want

Comment: Thanks Jake, math is not my strongest side. Good catch about the TakeDamage